# Find rectangles without corners using opencv

Tags: opencv

I have an image where I want to find contours but the "contours" in my image don't have corners.  Are there some tricks I can use to help find the rectangles that are implied by the lines in this image?  I thought about extending all the lines to form the corners but I worry about lines intersecting from other contours and how to determine which intersections I'm interested in.  I'm very new to opencv and I don't know much about image processing.  Thank you for any help you can give.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up implementing my own solution.  It isn't very graceful but it gets the job done.  I would be interested in hearing about improvements.  HoughLines2 didn't always give me good results for finding line segments and I had to mess around with the threshold value a lot for different scenarios.  Instead I opted for FindCountours where I took contours with two elements, I should be guaranteed 1 pixel wide lines.  After finding the lines I iterated through them and traced them out to find the rectangles.

Where points is a *CvSeq of the line endpoints

```
while(points->total>0){
  if(p1.x==-1&&p1.y==-1){
     cvSeqPopFront(points,&p1);
     cvSeqPopFront(points,&p2);
  }

  if((pos=findClosestPoint(&p1,&p2, points,maxDist))>=0){  
     p3 = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( points,pos );
     pos2 = (pos%2==0)?pos+1:pos-1; //lines are in pairs of points
     p4 = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( points,pos2 );

     if(isVertical(&p1,&p2) && isHorizontal(p3,p4)){
        printf("found Corner %d %d\n",p2.x,p3->y);
     } else if(isHorizontal(&p1,&p2) && isVertical(p3,p4) ){
        printf("found Corner %d %d\n",p3->x,p2.y);
     }

     memcpy(&p1,p3,sizeof(CvPoint));
     memcpy(&p2,p4,sizeof(CvPoint));
     cvSeqRemove(points, (pos>pos2)?pos:pos2);
     cvSeqRemove(points, (pos>pos2)?pos2:pos);
  } else {
     p1.x=-1;
     p1.y=-1;
  }
}

int findClosestPoint (CvPoint *p1, CvPoint *p2, CvSeq *points, int maxDist) {  
   int ret = -1,i;
   float dist, minDist = maxDist;
   CvPoint* test;
   int (*dirTest)(CvPoint *,CvPoint *);

   if(isVertical(p1,p2)){ //vertical line
      if(p2->y > p1->y) {//going down
         dirTest = isBelow;
      } else { // going up
         dirTest = isAbove;
      }
   } else if (isHorizontal(p1,p2)){ //horizontal line
      if(p2->x > p1->x) {//going right
         dirTest = isRight;
      } else { //going left
         dirTest = isLeft;
      }
   }

   for( i = 0; i < points->total; i++ )
   {
      test = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( points, i );
      if(dirTest(p2,test)){ //only test points in the region we care about
         dist = sqrt(pow(test->x - p2->x,2)+pow(test->y - p2->y,2));
         if(dist<minDist){
            minDist = dist;
            ret = i;
         }
      }
   } 
   return ret;
}

int isVertical(CvPoint *p1, CvPoint *p2){
   return p1->x == p2->x;
}
int isHorizontal(CvPoint *p1, CvPoint *p2){
   return p1->y == p2->y;
}
int isRight(CvPoint *pt1, CvPoint *pt2){
   return pt2->x > pt1->x;
}
int isLeft(CvPoint *pt1, CvPoint *pt2){
   return pt2->x < pt1->x;
}
int isBelow(CvPoint *pt1, CvPoint *pt2){
   return pt2->y > pt1->y;
}
int isAbove(CvPoint *pt1, CvPoint *pt2){
   return pt2->y < pt1->y;
}
```

Comment: How does this work? I'm guessing it finds the closest point and links them. And using the isVertical/etc functions, you check if its a vertical line or not.

Comment: Basically I iterate through the lines found by FindContours.  For the first line I determine its direction, so lets say it is going left to right.  I then look for the closest point in the remaining lines that would be to the right of the right most point of my first line.  The nearest point will be one end point of a line, I find the other and then determine the direction of this new line. If the new line is perpendicular to my first line I found a corner if it isn't then I just keep finding more lines which will inevitably be more to the right.  As I find lines I take them off the list.

Comment: In the above example once I do find a perpendicular line then I will be moving in a different direction.  So I may move left to right then bottom to top where I would only find points above my line etc.  Eventually findClosest will no longer find points as I specify a max distance and I will move onto another starting line segment found from FindContours

Answer (score 4):

Fit lines in your binary image with the [Hough transform](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/feature_detection.html?highlight=hough#cvHoughLines2) and fit rectangles to the orthogonally intersecting lines.

Comment: Jacob, thanks for the quick response.  I'm familiar with houghlines2 but I am actually using cvFindContours for contours with 2 points.  Houghlines didn't always give good results and I had to mess with the threshold too much.  I believe the real crux of the problem is fitting the rectangles, I couldn't figure out a good method but I did make something up which I will post.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try posing it as optimization problem. Rectangle is defined as 4D state vector (x,w,width,height) or 5D vector if you include rotation (x,y,width,height,rotation). For your current state you could do a gradient descent towards result of Hough lines to converge to the optimal state. Other option is using linear least squares: http://people.inf.ethz.ch/arbenz/MatlabKurs/node88.html

Answer (score 0):

Using the [hough transform](http://www.aishack.in/2010/03/the-hough-transform) you will be able to extract lines. Then you can calculate intersections of these lines to estimate the position of the rectangles.

Comment: I thought about taking the lines and extending them out and finding intersections but this leaves me with a few fake rectangles which I would have to cull out.  It would get worse with more rectangles.  I made a custom solution which isn't very elegant but i will post.